# Populate address into php form based on postcode and house number using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a PHP form which a user can fill in their house number and postcode and click a button to auto fill their address into empty fields. I am using Google Maps API but I am getting an error. The form fields contain [object Object] instead of the string value.

```js
    function getAddress(object) {
      postcode = jQuery(object).parent().siblings('.address-finder-postcode').children('input').val();
      housenumber = jQuery(object).parent().siblings('.address-finder-house').children('input').val();

      street = jQuery(object).parent().siblings('.address-finder-street').children('input');
      district = jQuery(object).parent().siblings('.address-finder-district').children('input');
      town = jQuery(object).parent().siblings('.address-finder-town').children('input');
      county = jQuery(object).parent().siblings('.address-finder-county').children('input');

      if (postcode == '' || housenumber == '') {
        alert('Please enter a postcode and house name or number');
        return;
      }

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/wp-content/themes/wfal/page-templates/find-address.php',
        data: {
          'postcode': postcode
        },
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery('input[name=address1]').val(housenumber);
          jQuery('input[name=address2]').val(street);
          jQuery('input[name=city]').val(town);
          jQuery('input[name=county]').val(county);

          console.log(data);
          street.val(data.route);
          if (data.locality != data.postal_town) {
            district.val(data.locality);
          }
          town.val(data.postal_town);
          county.val(data.administrative_area_level_2);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
      });
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('.address-finder-button').click(function() {
        getAddress(this);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="half-width">
        <p class="address-finder-house"><label for="address-finder-house">House name or number:</label><input type="text" name="address1" id="address-finder-house" value="" /></p>
      </div>

      <div class="half-width">
        <p class="address-finder-postcode"><span class="title">Postcode:</span><input type="text" id="address-finder-postcode" value="" /></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Find Address" class="address-finder-button" value="" /></p>
      </div>

      <div class="half-width">
        <span class="title">Street</span>
        <p class="address-finder-street"><input type="text" id="address-finder-street" name="address2" value="" /></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="half-width">
        <span class="title">Town/city</span>
        <p class="address-finder-town"><input id="address-finder-town" name="city" type="text" value="" /></p>
      </div>
      <div class="half-width">
        <span class="title">County</span>
        <p class="address-finder-county"><input id="rem-mort" name="county" type="text" value="" /> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```php
<?php
  // Get the postcode from the request
  $postcode = $_REQUEST['postcode'];

  // Get the latitude & longitude of submitted postcode
  $postcode = urlencode($postcode);
  $query = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . 
  $postcode . '&sensor=false';

  $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));
  $lat = $result->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  $lng = $result->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

  // Get the address based on returned lat & long
  $address_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . $lat . ',' . $lng . '&sensor=false';
  $address_json = json_decode(file_get_contents($address_url));
  $address_data = $address_json->results[0]->address_components;

  foreach($address_data as $data):
    $array[$data->types[0]] = $data->long_name;
  endforeach;

  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result on my website - [image]

Here is a screenshot of my console log - prnt.sc/ii7xza. As you can see the data isn't being inserted into the address fields. They stay blank.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the value in your success call back, you are referencing the object itself and not the data.

```
jQuery('input[name=address1]').val(housenumber);
```

housenumber in that instance is an object, best bet would be to do a console log on it and find out what the exact parameters are. and what you should wind up with is

```
jQuery('input[name=address1]').val(housenumber.value);
```

or something similar.

If you post more of your output we can determine the exact entry.

---

Given the sample data;

`jQuery('input[name=address1]').val(housenumber);` Should become `jQuery('input[name=address1]').val(data.street_number);`

It looks like from the screenshot, you just have to use the keys returned by your ajax call. You have to prefix your keys with `data.` because that is how you're passing the request's returned data into your call back function.

The documentation on `$.ajax()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
and documentaion on Ajax Events, http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/ the success callback is an event.

Comment: So here is a screenshot of my console log - https://prnt.sc/ii7xza. as you can see the data isn't being inserted into the address fields. They stay blank.

Comment: Well, it looks like `housenumber` doesn't exist in your data but `street_number` does.